# What are the steps taken with pip install in python

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a package via pip, but there were missing files from the zip file. So I copy the files and then compile with gcc. But now I cannot continue with the installation by calling pip install because it sees a pre-existing directory and will not proceed.
This is with pip version 1.5.6, but I thought that with earlier versions of pip that it was less fussy about this. 
What are the remaining steps to complete the package installation?

Comment: Are you asking about installing pip or a package using pip?

Comment: installing a package using pip

Answer (score 1):

uninstall then continue:

```
pip uninstall package-name
```

Comment: I don't want to uninstall it because I've copied in some files into the  pip home and compiled with gcc. I just want to continue from that point.

Comment: just install normally then.  $ python setup.py install

Comment: Corey, then how do I continue the setup after I have compiled with gcc and gotten a .o file. How do I complete the setup?